# Keep note sheet as black text on white background while Notes.app is in dark mode

Tags: macos, mojave, user-account, notes.app, dark-mode

I am enjoying [dark mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave#Dark_mode_and_accent_colors) in [macOS Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave). This includes the list boxes and sidebar in the [Notes.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notes_(Apple)#macOS_10.13). Except, the note sheet itself is awkward with white-text-on-black-blackground.

Is it possible to keep most of dark mode except the content of each note?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes, user preference

Yes, indeed, you can display your note sheets in Notes as black-ink-on-white.

Go to `Preferences` dialog box. While I did not notice it immediately, you can find a checkbox under the text-size slider. That checkbox is titled `Use dark backgrounds for note content`. Uncheck that box.

[image: screenshot of Notes.app <code>Preferences</code> panel]